# How to add a "lock screen and suspend" command to LXQt?

Tags: suspend, lxqt

I configured my Lubuntu 18.10 LXQt desktop so that it does not lock the screen on suspend – because that allows to resume my work much faster.

However sometimes when I want to transport the computer or leave it unattended, I want to lock the screen before suspending.

How can I have a shortcut for that, and a menu entry in the panel?

Comment: I found this question while looking for the option where I can configure if the session should be locked on suspend/hibernate and finally found it again under `Settings` -> `Session and Startup` -> `General` -> `Shutdown` -> `Lock Screen before sleep`-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Shortcut

1. Start `lxqt-config-globalkeyshortcuts` (or click "panel menu → Preferences → LXQt Settings → Shortcut keys").
2. Create a shortcut that executes the following command:

   ```
   sh -c "lxqt-leave --lockscreen && systemctl suspend"
   ```

### Menu entry

1. Create a file `~/.local/share/applications/lxqt-lock-suspend.desktop` with the following content:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Name=Lock and Suspend
   GenericName=LockSuspend
   Comment=lock the screen and suspend the machine
   Exec=sh -c "lxqt-leave --lockscreen && systemctl suspend"
   Icon=system-suspend
   Categories=System;X-Leave;
   OnlyShowIn=LXQt;
   ```
2. Refresh the LXQt menu by restarting the panel: press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to get to the `lxqt-runner` window and there execute the following commands, one after the other:

   ```
   killall lxqt-panel
   lxqt-panel
   ```

   Explanations:

   Executing it as one command `sh -c "killall lxqt-panel && lxqt-panel"` made my `lxqt-panel` lose its window management keyboard shortcuts. Probably in another way it can work.

   You could also execute this in a terminal window, but then it would make you lose your `lxqt-panel` when closing that terminal window. (Even when terminating the command with `&`. You can daemonize it to fix that but you have to look that up yourself ….)